# Creating a calculated column (uses aggregate function) in MS Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

The MS Access SQL query shown below produces a result set. I want to take the `completion_metric_query_result` column from the result and add it to an actual table as a computed column. Is there any way I can do this?

Previously I attempted to use an update query but update queries in access do not work with aggregate function like AVG().

```
SELECT 
    PROMIS_LT_Long_ID.Short_ID,
    FORMAT (100 * (AVG(IIF(PROMIS_LT_Long_ID.Status = 'Complete', 1.0, 0))), '#,##0.00') AS completion_metric_query_result
FROM 
    PROMIS_LT 
INNER JOIN
    PROMIS_LT_Long_ID ON PROMIS_LT.SubjectID = PROMIS_LT_Long_ID.Short_ID
GROUP BY 
    PROMIS_LT_Long_ID.Short_ID;
```

Result set:

```
SubjectID | completion_metric_query_result
----------+-------------------------------
02345800  | 12.00
13938432  | 12.50
13491349  | 0.00
12484028  | 15.00
12993248  | 75.00
```

Comment: `SELECT INTO` ???

Comment: Or INSERT INTO SELECT to an existing table. First DELETE records in table. Is this a multi-user split db?

Comment: Why do you even need this data in a table? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688880/update-query-with-aggregate-function

Comment: @June7 My boss wants it stored in a table. Do you think I can tell him the best would just be to leave it as a query in MS Access?

Comment: That is my opinion and aligns with 'best practice' principle.